# Check if the message sender has a specific role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm new in Discord bot coding and I want to create a command where the bot only replies if the message sender has a specific role.

According to the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager) I have to use `GuildMemberRoleManager.cache`. Sadly, it isn't working.

The whole command looks like this:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (
    message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'test' &&
    GuildMemberRoleManager.cache.has(AdminRole)
  )
    message.reply('test');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the author's roles. Only members have roles, so you will need to get the author as a member using [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member). `message.member` returns a `GuildMember` and `GuildMember`s have a [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) property that returns a `GuildMemberRoleManager` (the one you mentioned in your original post).

Its [`cache`](https://%20%20https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) property is a collection of the roles of this member, so you can use its [`has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) method to check if the user has the admin role:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  let adminRole = 'ADMIN_ROLE';
  let isAdmin = message.member.roles.cache.has(adminRole);

  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'test' && isAdmin)
    message.reply('test');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Define the variables which will make you easy to understand as you are new

```js
const guild = message.guild.id;
const role = guild.roles.cache.get("role id");
const cmduser = message.author;
const member = await guild.members.fetch(cmduser.id);
```

and make if statement like

```js
if(member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
      return message.channel.send("test")
    }
```

if you want bot to check if user have administrator perm than

```js
message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')
```

Check all perm flags on [Discord Perm Flags](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions)

So according to your code it will be

```js
const guild = message.guild.id;
const role = guild.roles.cache.get("role id");
const cmduser = message.author;
const member = await guild.members.fetch(cmduser.id);

client.on("messageCreate",(message) => {
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "test" && member.roles.cache.has(role.id))
        message.reply("test")
})
```